# How to append an element to a div with className that have a child elemnt with idName

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, createelement

MY html has multiple divs that share the same class name and they have input elements with unique ids, I want to append a span under all of these inputs with JavaScript without editing the html.

this is the part of html

```
<form name="form" onsubmit="return validate();" method="get">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pass">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" id="pass">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pass2">Re-Type Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass2" id="pass2">
   </div>
.
.
.
</form>
```

this my JS to create and append the span

```
const errorMessage = document.createElement('span');
errorMessage.textContent = "invalid input";
document.querySelector('.form-group').appendChild(errorMessage);
```

**But this only creates one span in the first div**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should get all items has class form-group with querySelectorAll

```
const arrayElement = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group');

for(let i = 0; i < arrayElement.length; i++)
{
 const errorMessage = document.createElement('span');
 errorMessage.textContent = "invalid input";
 arrayElement[i].appendChild(errorMessage);
}
```

more : https://jsfiddle.net/7znf685q/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll()` and iterate.

```
querySelectorAll(".form-group").forEach(form => {
    const errorMessage = document.createElement('span');
    errorMessage.textContent = "invalid input";
    form.appendChild(errorMessage);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

querySelector just gets the first instance.  You need to use querySelectorAll.  Then put everything inside a loop

```js
let group = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group') 
 
for (let i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
  const errorMessage = document.createElement('span');
  errorMessage.textContent = "invalid input";
  group[i].appendChild(errorMessage);
}
```

```html
<form name="form" onsubmit="return validate()" method="get">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pass">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" id="pass">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pass2">Re-Type Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass2" id="pass2">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You select the parent node through child id and then append you massage.

```
<script>
    const errorMessage = 'Password Not match';        
    document.getElementById("pass2").parentNode.append(errorMessage);
</script>
```

Comment: I want to append a span under ALL of these inputs